# Java: delete and recreate an array with a different size

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm very much a newbie with Java, so apologies if this seems like a stupid question or I'm doing things in a non-Java way (I'm more familiar with languages like C or Perl).

I'm working on an Android app which periodically updates its data from a webserver, storing its data between runs as shared preferences.

The data (either read from shared preferences or the online update) go into an array which will be used at various points around the app.

Now the problem is that the number of elements in the array needs to grow or shrink, depending on what's returned from the server. So I'm trying (and failing) to work out how to generate an array of a different size.

I know that in Java an array has a fixed length, so I'm hoping there must be some way of deleting it and then recreating it with new dimensions (there's no requirement to persist data between the two).

Sadly it's evidently not as easy as my guess of

```
    String[] myArray = new String[10];
    [...]
    myArray = new String[100];
```

for example, as my IDE throws up its hands in horror at that.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use `ArrayList<String>` which can dynamically expand, shrink  also you can remove items etc?

Comment: @PradeepSimha means the `ArrayList<String>` implementation of the `List` type.

Comment: Use `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(INITIAL_CAPACITY);`. It should expand as needed and have the same access-time of an array.

Comment: Crikey! Four answers within minutes of posting the question. Thanks all, I'll find out about arraylists, which I didn't know about.

Comment: @Beermad Such is stack overflow; awesome

Comment: @PradeepSimha should get credit for this. Too bad he didn't post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
String[] myArray = new String[10];
[...]
myArray = new String[100];
```

is absolutely correct syntactically.  In order to see this I suggest you create a small test java file in your favourite text editor (not an IDE), say, named `Test.java` and paste into it:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = new String[10];
        System.out.println("Size: " + arr.length);
        arr = new String[100];
        System.out.println("Size: " + arr.length);
    }
}
```

Then compile it from the command prompt - it compiles perfectly fine - and run from the command prompt:

```
$ vim Test.java
...
$ javac Test.java
$ java Test
Size: 10
Size: 100
```

If your IDE is complaining then either the IDE is wrong or you have an error elsewhere in the code.

Having said all that, if you need to delete/resize your array, then maybe arrays are not the right data structure for you and `List` is a better one.  Specifically, `ArrayList` and, more specifically, `ArrayList<String>`:

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then you can add items to it, retrieve by index, remove, etc.

Comment: Whats with the anti IDE content? Will this code not compile if used in an IDE?

Comment: @RichardTingle - Nothing at all, I use IDE all the time.  However it's easier to create a single java file outside an IDE than inside it.

Comment: I see your point now, I apologise, I'm used to the religious zeal of people on both sides, I see this isn't the case in this case however

Comment: It could well be that something else strange was causing my IDE to dislike that bit of code, though I don't know what. However, the suggestions of using ArrayList have worked nicely and not only been more flexible than arrays, they've also provided useful learning experience.

Comment: (continued as it timed out) I don't **usually** use IDEs, but as I haven't touched Java for a decade (and didn't really get on with it then) I've found Eclipse very useful in helping me work out where I'm going wrong with a language I'm still finding rather bewildering. (and the fact that it builds my Android APKs for me helps...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use List if there is no duplication value

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
```

or

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
```

This both can dynamically grow and shrink.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead primitive array:

```
List<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>(initialCapacity);
myArray.add("something");
```

If you really know what are you doing and want to have `String[]`, you have to copy all the elements into the new array with [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

```
String[] myArray = new String[10];
String[] newArray = new String[100];
System.arraycopy(myArray, 0, newArray, 0, myArray.length);
```